# EWS Autodiscover Shared Inbox

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices

I need to get into a shared inbox through a service account that does not have an email assigned to it, but it cannot find the shared inbox. Note that the service account does have access to the shared inbox.

Is it even possible to access an Office 365 shared inbox without an existing email account?

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
 service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("user@domain.com", "password");

//Individual User Email works
service.AutodiscoverUrl("user@email.com", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);

//Shared Inbox - Doesn't Work
service.AutodiscoverUrl("sharedinbox@email.com",RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);

//The authenticating account is a service account without an email.
```

Comment: NO. You can't access EWS account without valid email.